# Sql Query join suggestions

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering when having a parent table and a child table with foreign key like:

```
users
id | username | password |

users_blog
id | id_user | blog_title
```

is it ok to use id as auto increment also on join table (users_blog) or will i have problems of query speed?

also i would like to know which fields to add as PRIMARY and which as INDEX in users_blog table?

hope question is clear, sorry for my bad english :P

Comment: @guys what i forgot to tell about is that id_user is for 1 to many relationship (so i will JOIN when needed with users id), and also i would specify that id auto_increment in user_blog table is for paginate only users_blog table .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you actually need the id column in the users_blog table. I would make the id_user the primary index on that table unless you have another reason for doing so (perhaps the users_blog table actually has more columns and you are just not showing it to us?).

As far as performance, having the id column in the users_blog table shouldn't affect performance by itself but your queries will never use this index since it's very unlikely that you'll ever select data based on that column. Having the id_user column as the primary index will actually be of benefit for you and will speed up your joins and selects.

Answer (score 2):

What's the cardinality between the user and user_blog?  If it's 1:1, why do you need an `id` field in the user_blog table?

Comment: yep sorry i forgot to tell about cardinality is 1 to many not 1:1.

Answer (score 2):

> is it ok to use id as auto increment also on join table (users_blog)
>   or will i have problems of query speed?

Whether a field is auto-increment or not has no impact on how quickly you can retrieve data that is already in the database.

> also i would like to know which fields to add as PRIMARY and which as
>   INDEX in users_blog table?

The purpose of PRIMARY KEY (and other constraints) is to enforce the correctness of data. Indexes are "just" for performance.

So what fields will be in PRIMARY KEY depends on what you wish to express with your data model:

- If a `users_blog` row is identified with the `id` alone (i.e. there is a "non-identifying" relationship between these two tables), put `id` alone in the PRIMARY KEY.
- If it is identified by a combination of `id_user` and `id` (aka. "identifying" relationship) then you'll have these two fields together in your PK.

As of indexes, that depends on how you are going to access your data. For example, if you do many JOINs you *may* consider an index on `id_user`.

A good tutorial on index performance can be found at:

http://use-the-index-luke.com

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with having an auto increment `id` column on `users_blog`.

The primary key can be `id_user, id`. As for indexing, this heavily depends on your usage.

I doubt you will be having any database related performance issue with a blog engine though, so indexing or not doesn't make much of a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use `id` column in users_blog table you can join the id_user with users table. also auto increment is not a problem to performance

Answer (score -1):

- It is a good idea to have an identifier column that is auto increment - this guarantees a way of uniquely identifying the row (in case all other columns are the same for two rows)
- `id` is a good name for all table keys and it's the standard
- `<table>_id` is the standard name for foreign keys - in your case use `user_id` (not `id_user` as you have)
- mysql automatically creates indexes for columns defined as primary or foreign keys - there is no need to do anything here
- IMHO, table names should be singular - ie `user` not `users`

You SQL should look something like:

```
create table user (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ...
);

create table user_blog (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    id_user int not null references user,
    ...
);
```

Comment: "It is a good idea to have an identifier column that... guarantees a way of uniquely identifying the row (in case all other columns are the same for two rows)" -- so two distinct users can use the same `username` and `password` combination and when one of them logs in they may gain access to the other's account? That doesn't strike me as a good idea.

Comment: If your requirements are that other columns sets are *also* unique, then define a unique index over them. I'm talking more about the same data happening twice where that is not a problem - you just want to be able to chose which one to delete for example.

Comment: The case being discussed has columns `username` and `password`: when would it be a good idea to duplicate `username` in this table? I say never and would therefore suggest making `username` the sole key in this table.